# Javascript remove key and value array knowing value

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```
arr[1234]='foo'
arr[2345]='bar'
arr[6253]='cho'
```

I want to be able to delete the key => value pair when I know the value in one of the pairs, `bar` (for-instance).

So, if I deleted `bar` the array would then equal:

```
arr[1234]='foo'
arr[6253]='cho'
```

So, it would maintain both key and value in each remaining pair, and remove the key and value of the one whose value is specified.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you have some confusion between arrays and objects. If you [look at this example](http://jsfiddle.net/xhy1619t/), you can see that I've defined both an array and an object and assigned the array the index 100, and the object the key 100 (the integer is coerced to a string). The array has 91 empty slots and then the value, the object has only that single key/value pair. So I think you want an object and _not_ an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find property by its value in loop and use `delete` operator:

```
for (var key in arr) {
    if (arr[key] === "bar") {
        delete arr[key];
        break;
    }
}
```

Check the demo.

```js
var arr = {};
arr[1234] = 'foo';
arr[2345] = 'bar';
arr[6253] = 'cho';

for (var key in arr) {
    if (arr[key] === "bar") {
        delete arr[key];
        break;
    }
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var res_arr = arr.filter( function filterByValue(element){
        if (element != "bar"){
            return element
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf to get the index of a key in a array

```
var arr = ["foo", "bar"];
arr.indexOf("bar"); // 1
```

then you can delete a index using splice

```
arr.splice( arr.indexOf("foo"), 1 ); // arr = ["bar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr= new Array();
arr[1234]='foo';
arr[2345]='bar';
arr[6253]='cho';
delete arr[arr.indexOf('bar')];
```